# Android SDK not updating the installed packages

Tags: android

When i try to do "update all" from Android SDK and AVD Manager thru' windows environment i got following error msg -

Failed to fetch URL https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository.xml, reason: dl-ssl.google.com

can anybody pls let me know of the correct link from where it will fetch the packages ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing 'https' to 'http'